# Is it worth it to upgrade a Toshiba Satellite C55-A5300 laptop given the latest productivity software requirements?

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, upgrade, hardware-rec

I would like to upgrade a Toshiba Satellite C55-A5300 laptop so it can be as useful as it can be nowadays.

I haven’t needed to use much software for a few years now, and I’m not able to gauge whether a maxed out upgrade of this laptop would be up to running the latest versions of MS Office and Acrobat smoothly. Maybe even run some Photoshop and Lightroom?

I want to install the best CPU that will work optimally within the parameters of this laptop, including the laptop’s cooling capabilities. I ultimately want improved performance, but I want the performance to be as smooth as possible.

From what I gather the Pentium 2030M is the best processor this motherboard will accept. Am I on the right track?

I also plan to fully upgrade the memory and the hard disk speed with respective upgrades. What is the max memory per RAM slot (2 total)? What is the fastest speed of RAM I can use?

---

Copied from the Toshiba spec sheet:

> **Processor and Graphics**
>
> Intel® Celeron® Processor 1037U o (2M Cache, 1.80GHz)
>
> Mobile Intel® NM70 Express Chipset
>
> Mobile Intel® HD graphics with shared graphics memory Memory
>
> **Memory**
>
> Configured with 4GB DDR3 1333MHz (max 16GB) 2 main memory slots. One
> slot is occupied
>
> **Storage Drive**
>
> 500GB (5400 RPM) Serial ATA hard disk drive
>
> **Power**
>
> 45W (19V 2.37A) 100-240V/50-60Hz AC Adapter

Comment: The specs mention 32GB max, but that is almost certainly for 2 memory channels with 2 sticks in each channel (4 DIMMS total) which would be a "normal" desktop configuration. Laptops tend to only have space for one DIMM per channel (2 total) but that doesn't mean you can use a stick twice as large. In either case your max is probably 8GB DIMMS.

Comment: You have now posted three hyper specific questions — [here](https://superuser.com/q/1609055/167207), [here](https://superuser.com/q/1609100/167207) and [here](https://superuser.com/q/1609082/167207) of course — on the same topic: Upgrading a Toshiba Satellite C55-A5300. While this site is not about hardware recommendations, it does seem like you took the help center advice of focusing each question to one thing way to literally. You can simply ask all you need to ask in one question: Is upgrading this machine possible?

Comment: And to comment specifically to the content of the question: This machine is not worth the effort. It dates back to 2013 and the CPU can’t be upgraded. In fact the only things you can upgrade on it are RAM and SSD. But the cost of the RAM and SSD won’t give you that much more performance. My opinion? If it is still functional, sell it on eBay and use the money to get  better, more modern machine. And if you need help on spending $$$: Divide the total cost by 7 years. If that per year cost is reasonable, get the machine. Invest more at the outset to give the machine a longer life as years pass.

Answer (score 3):

You need a better CPU but the CPU is soldered to the motherboard and is not replaceable; you should add more memory; and an upgrade of the hard disk drive to an SSD drive.

So it is not economical at all to upgrade this machine. Parts will cost more than its overall value.

So if your questions is: Is it worth the upgrade? No, not in my opinion.

Best course of action:  Use it until you can replace it with a faster and more modern machine with Windows 10 Pro pre-installed.